# Admob don't show rewarded video because of package name

Tags: admob, rewardedvideoad

has anyone experienced this problem:
I've just released my game on Google Play. Banner and interstitial ads are showing just fine, but rewarded video never show. It always return error code: No fill. I changed my game's package name to another one (of a famous game on store) and it showed video normally, but for my package name and arbitrary name it doesn't show at all.

Comment: It might not be because of the package name. May be the code integration may be wrong try reintegrating the ad.

Comment: The code can't be wrong because I also tested on Admob's sample. The problem is the same.

Comment: I have never come across any such incident. But my suggestion will be try changing the package name again but do not keep an existing package name keep something new unique. Also you can try reintegrating the ads sdk. There is a possibility but as per me very less that they are providing the ads to very famous games and not the one which are not famous. You can also try using some other AD Network if you are not satisfied with AdMob's performance.